# What kind of database refactoring tools are there?

Tags: database, refactoring

I am looking for something to integrate to my CI workflow.
I've heard of [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com) but I'm looking for something else. The reason I don't like dbdeploy is I don't want to install java on my server.

I would prefer of course that the solution doesn't involve stringing some shell scripts together.

Answer (score 16):

[**Here**](http://flywaydb.org) is a **feature comparison** between

- Flyway
- Liquibase
- c5-db-migration
- dbdeploy
- mybatis
- MIGRATEdb
- migrate4j
- dbmaintain
- AutoPatch

Comment: Is it me, or are these *all* Java tools? I (and OP) don't want to deploy a Java stack.

Comment: This is not a complete or unbiased feature comparison either.

Comment: Feel free to suggest improvements/corrections on the issue tracker at github.com/flyway/flywaydb.org

Answer (score 6):

It's not a tool, but Ambler and Sadalage's book, [Refactoring Databases: Evolutionary Database Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321293533) is quite good.

Answer (score 5):

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/) will probably do everything you need.  Expensive though.

EDIT - Specifically: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/

Comment: Redgate is, as "they" say, da bomb.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that you like dbDeploy and the fact that you do not want to install java on your server.  Are you aware of [the .NET port](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdeploy-net) of this tool?

I used this recently with a team and we were very happy with it.  In our case we were targeting SQL 2000, but it could easily be configured to run against other DB platforms, including MySQL.  Of course it will require you to have the .NET Framework installed on the server... if that's an acceptable prerequisite vs. the java runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Possible it's not your case, but if you decide to use Java take a look at [liquibase](http://liquibase.org/)

Answer (score 2):

for those people who are interested in liquibase, but don’t like xml migrations.
Take a look at [groovy-liquibase](https://github.com/tlberglund/groovy-liquibase), a plugin that supports groovy migrations

Liquibase is great in structure, but misses with xml migrations. This plugin solves that problem

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Redgate is magic. And Not that expenssive for what it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Agile DBRIRE](http://www.thisisagile.com/dbrire) for Continuous Integration workflow. It's easy to set and allows to generate test db from Dev DB. Also it allows to generate incremental DB updates for Staging and Production. The tool can compare DEV and Staging/Production DB and generate metadata and data update SQL scripts. The tool is free.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team system (database edition) does some refactoring.

I read the Refactoring databases book.  I think it's helpful.

But in software dev, you build tests so that you are safe refactoring.  They don't touch on tests in the Refactoring Databases book, which was my big disappointment with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think those tools are very good, but for my purpose I have written a custom own. The main reason for this was because of I'm working on a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database, so none of the listed tools worked.

Of course it isn't as powerful as the tools from Redgate but you get the most important features very quick.

It's able to rename all kinds of database objects and migrating columns to other tables and create a diff script for 2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

An important part of [Refactoring Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321293533) is the migrations part.
A .NET migrations solution that does not require EF or Java is Rob Reynold's [Roundhouse](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse)

Might be worth checking out.